# How to set rootViewController for navigation view controller and tabbar controller in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have this problem. When i set rootViewController for TabbarController, it show correctly. But i set another rootViewController for navigation bar, TabbarController will not able to display. Any idea?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

    self.window.rootViewController = [[DCTabBarController alloc] init];
    DCTabBarController *tabBar = (DCTabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    [tabBar setSelectedIndex:2];

    Map_ViewController *vc = [[Map_ViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *rootNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    [rootNav.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbarBackImage"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    rootNav.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [rootNav.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil]];

    LeftViewController *leftVC = [[LeftViewController alloc] init];

    RightViewController *rightVC = [[RightViewController alloc] init];

    XLSlideMenu *slideMenu = [[XLSlideMenu alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootNav];

    slideMenu.leftViewController = leftVC;
    slideMenu.rightViewController = rightVC;
    self.window.rootViewController = slideMenu;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

After applied Adeel solution, here is the output.But items in tabbar will not display accordingly.
[image]

Comment: That's because in this line of code `self.window.rootViewController = slideMenu` you are setting `XLSideMenu` as the rootViewController of your application's window.

Comment: Hi Adeel, yeah, but how can i set it for both? Now only will show slidemenu and tabbar will not display accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure but from your code it appears that you want to set the `XLSlideMenu` as application's rootViewController and `DCTabBarController` as the slide menu's rootViewController. Only the `Map_ViewController` doesn't make any sense. Can you share the screenshot of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One important thing to mention here is that an application's window can have only one rootViewController (of course). Like I said in my comment as well, you probably want to do something like this.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

    Map_ViewController *vc = [[Map_ViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *rootNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    [rootNav.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbarBackImage"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    rootNav.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [rootNav.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil]];

    DCTabBarController *tabBar = [[DCTabBarController alloc] init];
    [tabBar setViewControllers:@[rootNav]];
    self.window.rootViewController = tabBar;

    LeftViewController *leftVC = [[LeftViewController alloc] init];

    RightViewController *rightVC = [[RightViewController alloc] init];

    XLSlideMenu *slideMenu = [[XLSlideMenu alloc] initWithRootViewController:tabBar];

    slideMenu.leftViewController = leftVC;
    slideMenu.rightViewController = rightVC;
    self.window.rootViewController = slideMenu;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Hi Adeel, thx for your answer. However, i realise that my tabbar item does not display accordingly.Only can see the tabbar. Any idea?

Comment: This way I can't say anything. You need to show how it is displayed and what do you expect? You should update your question and provide more detail.

Comment: Hi adeel, screenshot as attached after i apply your suggestion. By right i have "Home", "category", "Map", and etc item in tabbar but now didnot display accordingly. And inside my navigation bar, i have other modules like merchant, setting and etc.

Comment: Hi adeel, i have solve my problem by using your solution with changed this code  DCTabBarController *tabBar = [[DCTabBarController alloc] init];
   [tabBar setViewControllers:@[rootNav]];
    self.window.rootViewController = tabBar; to self.window.rootViewController = [[DCTabBarController alloc] init];
    DCTabBarController *tabBar = (DCTabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    [tabBar setSelectedIndex:2];. Thx

Comment: @Test87 that won't display. My suggestion was to resolve the `rootViewController` issue. The tab bar items do not display because they are not set. To fix this problem you need instantiate all the view controllers to be shown in the tab bar controller and set the tab bar item for each of these view controller.